# Large Number of Columns in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a large number of records (10,000, increasing every day) that essentially is a report containing a large amount of data. All of this data, which are simply numeric measurements, needs to be stored.

The issue is, there are over 200 of these measurements, and I need to query them. For example, "for reports created between January and March of 2012, what is the average height of each gender, sorted by weight?" In order to have the flexibility to query any of the measurements, each of them needs their own column.

Right now, I store each of the fields in a JSON array and simply store it in a single column. This is fine for this portion of development where I do not have the querying tool completed, but I will need to build this soon... Theoretically I could pull all of the records from the database and sort them using PHP (when they are objects or arrays), but that seems needlessly complex and dangerous when dealing with so many rows.

Are there any issues with large (200+) column tables in MySQL with tens of thousands of rows, whether it is performance or data integrity? Or, are there any alternatives to pulling *everything* and sorting it using some server side language?

Some random info about my data:

- Each report has over 200 measurements
- Each measurement needs to be able to be queried
- The measurements are mostly integers or floating point numbers, but there are a few strings

Comment: There's a hard limit of 4,096 columns per table, but that can be reduced by other storage factors. MySQL shouldn't gawk at 200 columns, but you have some design decisions to make. Maybe 50 of those columns are fundamentally different from the other 150, so you could split them up into two tables that have a column with a unique identifier to map them together (which would exist in a parent table).

Comment: I knew about the hard limit, but I wasn't sure if 200 would be a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your dialemma, and in the (presumably short-lived) absence of a database expert I will give you my opinion.

For the sake of sanity break up your data. Lets say you're storing info on people. You don't need 200 columns in 1 table. You should split them up and have multiple columns in lots of tables. e.g.

```
tblGeneralCharacteristics:
 - colEyeColor
 - colHairColor
 - colHeight
 - colWeight

tblInterests:
 - colFaveColor
 - colFaveSport

tblRelationships
 - colMother
 - colFather
 - colBrother
 - colSister
```

This way is much better. Computationally I doubt it matters much. Obviously with each query you're getting less data back, so for some reports (where you might not need to get all the data, or trawl through all the data) it might be quicker (although if you index the database properly then it shouldn't be an issue).

Onto the next issue. That of the amount of records in the database. If 10,000 is starting to get a little large, its time to start caching.

Now, as far as I am concerned there is no right or wrong way to cache data. What you need is what you need. So for instance, in your question you mentioned getting average heights for weight for records input between Jan & March 2012. Well... you could write a cron script which calculates the average heights for weight for all the records input that month and stores this in a different table somewhere. Then when you come to create your report, you only need to get the values for Jan, Feb & March and avg them... that's much easier. Instead of doing a computational query on potentially thousands of rows, you're doing a cron query (which doesn't matter how long it takes) on a couple of hundred rows, and then the actual report only queries 3 rows.

Another trick is, the more calculations you can do in SQL the better. If you want to average fields/records, or total something then send it with your SQL query. The SQL server will do the computation and return the result, rather than returning you huge amounts of data to sift through. I know this isn't always easy/useful, but the more you can get SQL to do the better.

Hope this helps. Like I said I'm sure a database expert is itching to give you some more insightful advice. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) I'm not entirely sure about breaking it up, though. Each of the measurements has a name like an excel cell (B12), so there'd be no point from a readability standpoint. These all map to height, weight, age, etc, but it's not clear just from looking at the DB-- you have to look at the array I have to map they keys to the measurement types. Rather than complicate things, if possible, I'd rather just have everything in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Store them all separately. Mysql has a limit of 4096 columns per table, and 65536 bytes per row. You aren't going to hit that with mostly numeric data and a few strings.

You shouldn't do any data operations in php, that's where sql shines. 200 columns and 10,000 rows is rather small in the grand scheme of things, just index your table properly and performance should be fine even if you don't.