# Large Numbers Of Columns In Database

Tags: sql, database

I have been doing some research into this issue and still have not been able to make up a satisfactory decision.

This question came closest but still does not really help my situation.
[Large Number of Columns in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302087/large-number-of-columns-in-mysql-database)

I am basically creating a site of "who would win in a fight" to settle the long standing batman vs superman style arguments where users can vote on who they think would win.

Users will have the option to submit a "fighter" to the website who will then be randomly matched to every other fighter for future users to vote on.

I want to obviously keep statistics on all of the match ups to display to the users.

Now i will have a table named lets say FIGHTERS. this will store info like primary key, name, description, but not fight results.

As for storing the fight results i can see two options.

Option A: Create a table for each fighter to count the amount of winning votes they have vs every other fighters primary key.

Option B: Create One Large votes table which would have an equal amount of column's and rows indexed by the primary keys of the fighters. Then for example to get the stats for fighter1 vs fighter4 i would query row 1 (fighter1 PK1) Column 4 (for fighter 4 PK4) to get the amount of fighter 1 wins vs fighter 4, and then repeat but query row 4 (PK4 for fighter 4), column 1 to get fighter 4 wins vs fighter1. This table would obviously get very large when hundreds (thousands?) of fighters are added.

(Hope that was not too confusing!)

So i guess my question is, is it better to have hundreds of small tables (which will all need to have columns and rows added when a new fighter is added). Or to have one large table?

Im totally 50/50 with this so please any advice or other ways i could achieve this would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry for leaving this out. The voting i had in mind would work basically as a count of overall votes for each fighter in favour of winning the fight vs each other fighter.

Comment: Neither option you presented strikes my fancy.  I suggest a standard relational database, normalized of course.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Im aware of (but suck at) normalization, did it at uni - was the worst module of them all for me! Could not get my head around it and dreaded the day i would need to use it in the real world!

Comment: It was taught for a reason.  It's the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: The beauty of hindsight.

Comment: If you still have your course material from university, it might help you with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following clarification I would consider

```
CREATE TABLE FightResults
(
Fighter1Id INT REFERENCES FIGHTERS(FighterId),
Fighter2Id INT REFERENCES FIGHTERS(FighterId),
Fighter1Votes INT,
Fighter2Votes INT,
CHECK (Fighter1Id < Fighter2Id ),
PRIMARY KEY (Fighter1Id,Fighter2Id)    
)
```

You have a row for each matchup. Gorilla vs Shark, Lion vs Tiger etc. The check and PK constraints ensure the same matchup isn't represented more than once.

This does assume that the fights will have a fixed number of participants at two. If this isn't the case then a more flexible schema is

```
CREATE TABLE Fight
(
FightId INT PRIMARY KEY,
/*Other columns with fight metadata*/
)

CREATE TABLE FightResult
(
FightId INT REFERENCES Fight(FightId),
FighterId INT REFERENCES FIGHTERS(FighterId),
Votes INT,
PRIMARY KEY (FightId,FighterId)
)
```

But this does add quite possibly unnecessary complexity to your queries.

You may also want to prevent multiple votes on the same contest by the same user. In that case you might use something like (assuming two fighters per contest again)

```
CREATE TABLE Fights
(
FightId INT PRIMARY KEY,
Fighter1Id INT REFERENCES FIGHTERS(FighterId),
Fighter2Id INT REFERENCES FIGHTERS(FighterId),
CHECK (Fighter1Id < Fighter2Id )   
)    

CREATE TABLE Votes
(
FightId INT REFERENCES Fights(FightId),
UserId INT REFERENCES Users(UserId),
Vote INT CHECK (Vote IN (1,2)),
PRIMARY KEY (FightId,UserId)   
)
```

But possibly keeping denormalised vote totals around for performance reason.

Comment: Would you need to keep separate track of votes for each fighter?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Possibly. The question doesn't make that clear as far as I can see. A vote for Fighter1  could increment the netvotes and a vote for fighter2 decrement it. It depends if they need to display the vote breakdowns.

Comment: That sounds workable. Hopefully this site is a huge success so we can finally get an answer to [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard - That's a good point. We might need to add a column for arena (land vs water) as that could obviously affect the result.

Comment: Sorry for leaving out information. Please see my edit. Does this effect your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if the constraint you typed is what you had in mind, but aren't you missing a column?   The result?

Comment: @loveforfire33 - If I understood your edit correctly then you would want to know 10 votes for Gorilla vs 6 for Shark? I will edit with that in mind.

Comment: But i should also mention (incase it was not clear - apologies) Gorilla and shark can also be matched to every other fighter in the database.

Comment: @loveforfire33 - I see. Well each such distinct matchup would be regarded as an individual fight in my schemas. The `Fighter1Id,Fighter2Id` idea would probably make the most sense.

Comment: I really like this solution, thank you very much to all who helped.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to create 2 tables:

1. Fighters with FighterId (primary key) and all the other data.
2. FightResult: FightResultId (primary key), FighterId1, FighterId2, FightResult. The two columns FighterIdX are foreign keys to Fighter.

This will make it easy to query and add votes and will keep it simple and easy to understand.

You can also add info like which user voted for a fight (foreign keys to users) to the second table if you like.

Comment: Downvoted for the suggestion of adding user info to the FightResult table.

Comment: Why? It may be needed in some cases. And I wanted to point the ability to extend that table if needed. Please explain more.

Comment: User info should be in it's own table.  So should votes for that matter.

Comment: I meant to record which user voted on this fight (foreign key to users table). You could use it to display voting history to the user.

Comment: If i understand this right this would create a table similar to option 2 i mentioned but instead of using hundreds of columns using hundreds of rows? (Apologies - I dont think i initially explained the voting system well enough if this effects the answer - please see my edit)

Comment: That would restrict it to one person voting.

Comment: @DanBracuk one person per one set of fighters - I didn't expect it otherwise.

Comment: @loveforfire33 yes, there would be many rows. This is what database systems are designed to handle so there's no problem with that.